# How can I get a data list as string in Postgres SQL query?

Tags: postgresql

My tables are

```
create table parents(
id integer,
name text,
parent_childs text);

create table childs(
parent_id integer,
name text);
```

Data:

```
insert into parents values (1, 'Mueller');

insert into childs values (1, 'Peter');

insert into childs values (1, 'Hans');
```

How can I select this data in format:

```
parent_name    childs
------------------------
Mueller        Peter, Hans
Bayer          Anna, Petra, Max
```

And I looking for a simple update to write all names from childs from one parents entry in column parents.parent_childs like 'Peter, Hans'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update :

[**string_agg(expression, delimiter)**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) - *input values concatenated into a string, separated by delimiter*

In your case :-

- expression :- `childs.name`
- delimiter  :-`,`

---

```
update parents 
set parent_childs =t.cname 
    from(
         select parent_id
               ,string_agg(childs.name,',') cname 
         from childs group by parent_id
        )t
where t.parent_id=parents.id
```

---

> How can I select this data in format:
>
> ```
> parent_name    childs
> ------------------------
> Mueller        Peter, Hans
> Bayer          Anna, Petra, Max
> ```

Try this :

```
select parents.name as parent_name
      ,string_agg(childs.name,',') childs 
from childs 
inner join  parents on childs.parent_id=parents.id 
group by parent_id,parents.name
```